# InstallShield prerequisities (error -7067)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installshield-le

I created InstallShield setup project in VS2013 by importing VS2010 Setup deployement project (with the integrated wizard). When I try to compile it, it says:

> ISEXP : error : -7067: Your project contains InstallShield
>   prerequisites. A Setup.exe setup launcher is required if you are
>   building a release that includes InstallShield prerequisites. Change
>   your release settings to build Setup.exe, or remove the prerequisites
>   from your project.

Well I could enable Setup.exe generation, but the problem is, there should be no prerequisities. In project assistant view I have "No" option checked where there's a choice "Does your application require any software to be installed on the machine?" and in 5 -> Requirements nothing is checked.

I also noticed that when I create the IS setup project manually (without import) and set all the things myself, the problem is gone. So it has something to do with the old Setup Deployement settings. I also noticed that I got these two warnings with VS2010 Setup project:

> WARNING: The version of the .NET Framework launch condition '.NET
>   Framework 4 Client Profile' does not match the selected .NET Framework
>   bootstrapper package. Update the .NET Framework launch condition to
>   match the version of the .NET Framework selected in the Prerequisites
>   Dialog Box. WARNING: The target version of the .NET Framework in the
>   project does not match the .NET Framework launch condition version
>   '.NET Framework 4 Client Profile'. Update the version of the .NET
>   Framework launch condition to match the target version of the.NET
>   Framework in the Advanced Compile Options Dialog Box (VB) or the
>   Application Page (C#, F#).

Don't know where these two warnings came from, they hadn't always been there. The thing is that it is a C++ project and therefore should have no .NET framework dependency at all. Don't really know whether these two problems are somehow related, I just need to to compile the InstallShield LE project in VS2013.

Is there any way I can fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InstallShield lets you specify which prerequisites are included in the `Redistributables` view (under `Specification Application Data`). Your project probably includes at least one prerequisite.

Comment: Thank's that was it. .NET 4.0 was ticked. But how come? Why would C++ project need .NET?

Comment: Probably the converter saw something that it interpreted as meaning your original project needed .NET 4.0. This could be an incorrect setting on the original project or an incorrect import of it. If it's the latter, the official support channel can take bug reports.

Comment: Considering the warning I posted (from the original VS2010 project) it is likely to be the first option. Where would I find settings like that? It is a C++ project after all...